# How do I set the system time?

Tags: c#, date, calendar, hijri

On windowsXP and onwards, if you set the datetime to hijri calendar an option is provided to adjust it in "Regional and Language Options".

What I want to do is to either adjust the hijri date using C# or set system date to my own calculated hijri system date?

Any help

Answer (score 1):

Changing system datetime can be done by importing the SetLocalTime function:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetLocalTime([In] ref SYSTEMTIME lpLocalTime);
```

You have to calculate your local time based on the hijri time.